# Printing wrong python

Tags: python

I've recently gotten into coding, so I don't know a lot, which is why I am coming here for help. I am currently coding a game using python (Not a complicated game based off of what I am thinking of making) it's basically just a card game one of my friends made up. My only problem so far is one of my variables are returning wrong, and right at the same time?

This is the code that's being wonky:

```
Card = "Nothing"

def Draw_Card():
    Rank = random.randint(1, 13)
    print(Rank)
    Card = str(Rank)
    print(Card)

    if Rank == 11:
        Card = "J"
    elif Rank == 12:
        Card = "Q"
    elif Rank == 13: 
        Card = "K"

    Suit = random.randint(1, 4)
    if Suit == 1:
        Card = Card + "D"
    elif Suit == 2:
        Card = Card + "C"
    elif Suit == 3:
        Card = Card + "H"
    elif Suit == 4:
        Card = Card + "S"

Top()
Help()
Top()
print("And the game begins!")
time.sleep(2)
Top()
Card = "Nothing"
Draw_Card()
print(Card)
```

ignore the Top() functions and other functions, all that matters is the Draw_Card() and the print(Card) Running through this code will return

7,
7,
Nothing

assuming that 7 is the random value generated. Card is being printed right, when in the Draw_Card() function, but not when its outside the function. I dont understand why this is happening, and would apreciate some help

also another thing is the Card = "Nothing" doesnt work inside the function, it returns as Card is undefines, but thats besides the point

Comment: Is your code really indented as shown in your question?

Comment: What are you intending to print out? Just include a minimal example of the output you would wish to achieve. Also, to reiterate the above, is your code actually indented like this or would you like it to be edited for proper indents?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Draw_Card`, the name `Card` refers to a local variable. How about returning it?

At the end of the function, add

```
return Card
```

And outside the function, do:

```
Card = Draw_Card()
```

---

Another option would be to declare the name to be from the global scope:

```
def Draw_Card():
    global Card
    Rank = random.randint(1, 13)
    print(Rank)
    ...
```

But I would generally avoid `global` and `nonlocal` if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print the suit and the card when you call the Draw_Card function (i.e. 7D), then you can move the `print(card)` to the bottom of the Draw_Card function.

Also in order to change the Card variable outside the function, you'd need to place `global Card` at the top of the function.

```
import random

Card = "Nothing"
def Draw_Card():
  global Card
  Rank = random.randint(1, 13)

  Card = str(Rank)

  if Rank == 11:
      Card = "J"
  elif Rank == 12:
      Card = "Q"
  elif Rank == 13: 
      Card = "K"

  Suit = random.randint(1, 4)
  if Suit == 1:
      Card = Card + "D"
  elif Suit == 2:
      Card = Card + "C"
  elif Suit == 3:
      Card = Card + "H"
  elif Suit == 4:
      Card = Card + "S"
  print(Card)


print("And the game begins!")
Card = "Nothing"
Draw_Card()
print(Card)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function just needs to `return`, you should focus on using `return` and then `print` the values returned

```
def Draw_Card():
    Rank = random.randint(1, 13)
    Card = str(Rank)

    if Rank == 11:
        Card = "J"
    elif Rank == 12:
        Card = "Q"
    elif Rank == 13: 
        Card = "K"

    Suit = random.randint(1, 4)
    if Suit == 1:
        Card = Card + "D"
    elif Suit == 2:
        Card = Card + "C"
    elif Suit == 3:
        Card = Card + "H"
    elif Suit == 4:
        Card = Card + "S"

    return Card

print("And the game begins!")
Card = "Nothing"
Card = Draw_Card()
print(Card
```

> ```
> And the game begins!
> QS
> ```